# Django 1.10: "new style" middleware equivalent of `process_request()`

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-middleware

How would one create "new style" middleware, which fulfills an equivalent implementation to using the `process_request()` hook with the "old style"?

I've already adapted pre 1.10 middleware `process_request()` using `MiddlewareMixin`...

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class MyCustomMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        # My request logic
        return response
```

I'd like to know how to do a "pure" >1.9 "new style" implementation.  I tried doing so by implementing `__init__()` and `__call__()` like this without luck:

```
class MyCustomMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # My request logic
        return response
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here an example...

```py
class TimeStampMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Now you can get the timestamp in every request from yours views! (is only an example)

Comment: `process_request` was supposed to be called even for unknown views, with this new style of middleware it looks to be called just as "emulation layer" only for known views - so I cannot process requests that do not map to any view :(