# After upgrade to Django 1.11 append_slash no longer works

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-settings

In Django 1.9 (and Python 3.4) the default of APPEND_SLASH worked correctly, i.e. I could enter 'localhost:8000/ideatree/videos'
and the trailing slash would be added.

After an upgrade to Django 1.11 (and Python 3.6), APPEND_SLASH is no longer working.

I've looked for deprecation notices but so far found nothing that seems to apply. (side question:  how do you turn 'loud deprecation warnings' back on, as they were in previous versions?)

Here is my main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [   url(r'^(?i)ideatree/', include('ideatree.urls'),
 name='home'),
]
```

and the urls.py from the included app_space:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'ideatree'
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
   url(r'^(?i)features/$', views.features, name='features'),
   url(r'^(?i)videos/$', views.videos, name='videos')
]
```

Both these url.py files are unchanged except that in Django 1.9 I had

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
```

in the main urls.py, but 'patterns' is now deprecated and throws a warning.

As before, I do not have APPEND_SLASH set in settings.py, relying on its default value of True, though I tried explicitly setting it to True with the same result.

Here's my middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Here's the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/ideatree/videos

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^(?i)ideatree/ ^$ [name='index']
^(?i)ideatree/ ^(?i)features/$ [name='features']
^(?i)ideatree/ videos/$ [name='videos']
```

I also tried clearing the browser cache, and using a different browser in case the cache still didn't get cleared.

Logging to file at level DEBUG or level INFO shows nothing, an empty file (warning: my logging setup is untested).

There's got to be something I'm overlooking.

Comment: Does the redirect work if you remove `(?i)` from your regexes in your main and app urls?

Comment: It does not work with (?i) removed from the regexes in both urls.  I also removed the app_name just in case.  Same result.

Comment: I'm surprised that the patterns in the error message do not consistently contain `^(?i)`. Are you posting your exact code and error message?

Comment: Do you have `MIDDLEWARE` in your settings (added in Django 1.10)?

Comment: Ah, yes.  I must be using Django 1.9 middleware.  It works after 1) changing MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to MIDDLEWARE, 2) importing the MiddlewareMixin per [so]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876355/django-1-10-new-style-middleware-equivalent-of-process-request , and 3) deleting SessionAuthenticationMiddleware since it no longer appears in Django 1.10 docs.   I'll have to go through the docs to make sure the middleware functionality is still complete.  @Alasdair can you post as an answer so I can accept?  Many thanks, would never have found this without your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django introduced new middleware in Django 1.10. You should use the `MIDDLEWARE` setting if you are using [new-style middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/), and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` if you are using [old-style middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/).

If you are using Django 1.10 or 1.11, then the old `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting is still supported, so Django should continue to redirect with the appended slash.

However, once you upgrade to Django 2.0, the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting is ignored and you must switch over to `MIDDLEWARE`.

When you switch over to `MIDDLEWARE`, you should remove `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` since it has no effect in 1.10 and 1.11, and is removed completely in Django 2.0.

Comment: Maybe it was also an interaction between MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and SessionAuthenticationMiddleware classes, which don't appear in Django 1.11 docs, since it didn't work until they were removed?

Comment: No, `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` shouldn't cause any problems. In Django 1.11 it's a stub class for backwards compatibility reasons. It doesn't have any effect but you don't have to remove it from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: If I don't comment out I SessionAuthenticationMiddleware I get "ImportError: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class".  And the middleware I'm using is the list straight out of the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware.

Comment: You shouldn't get that error if you include `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` - the middleware [still exists in Django 1.11](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7e3f8e05eb56cbd01f50b811c551a7a79b250ef7/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L27). If you do not need backwards compatibility with other versions of Django then it's a good idea to remove it. My point was that `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` does not explain your original problem.

Comment: Yes,   add_slash now works even without importing MiddlewareMixin to update middleware from 1.9 to 1.11 style, as long as I don't use SessionAuthenticationMiddleware.  There's something else going on.  I suspect something with the (?i) regex as you mentioned before.

Comment: All the middleware classes you are using come with Django. They already use `MiddlewareMixin` in Django 1.11. You only need `MiddlewareMixin` if you are writing your own middleware that you want to be compatible with `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `MIDDLEWARE`.

Comment: Are you sure you're running Django 1.11.X? The message *ImportError: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class* is what I'd expect in Django 2.0. Could you have the 2.0 alpha installed?

Comment: Embarrassing but true.  It was Django 2.0 alpha.  Everything works as expected in Django 1.11.  This is the real answer.  Thanks again @Alasdair

Comment: Yes, upgrading to Django 2.0 explains the errors you saw. In Django 2.0, then the  `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting will be ignored, `MIDDLEWARE` will default to `None` if it's not defined in your settings, and the redirect will stop working because the common middleware will no longer be enabled.